# Is it permissible to say "Shabbos/Shabbat" in the bathroom?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shemos-sacred-names, bathroom

I once heard or read somewhere that Shabbos/Shabbat is one of the names of Hashem.

1- Is there a source for this?

2- If it's true, can I say "Shabbos/Shabbat" in the bathroom?

Comment: I thought the issue was the second half of the phrase - not "Shabbat" but "Shalom."

Answer (score 4):

The [Chessed Lealafim (85,1)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7849&st=&pgnum=151) (R' Eliezer Papo) brings down Zohar that says that HaShem is called Shabbos. (He writes: דקב״ה שבת איקרי).

Chessed Lealafim says that it is not allowed to say Shabbos in the bathroom. When the [Kaf Hachaim (85,7)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8140&st=&pgnum=279) discusses things that are assur to say in the bathroom, he says: אף לפ״ד החס״ל (even according to the da'as of Chessed Lealafim) that you can't say Shabbos in dirty places.

From the way the Kaf Hachaim quotes this opinion, it seems like theremay be those who argue, and hold that Shabbos is allowed to say in unclean places (e.g. Bath-house, bathroom, etc...). 
I heard in the name of Rabbi Triebitz that he said it’s permitted, but I haven't confirmed if the source is trustworthy. So please ask your Rav.

Answer (score 0):

I bring the Chessed Le’alafim, quotes the Zohar on the Gemara in Berachot that says that *Shabbat* is one the names of Hashem. The Halacha also says that mentioning Hashem's Name in the bathroom [let alone speaking] is forbidden. Therefore, the Poskim bring down that mentioning Shabbat is forbidden.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Ariel! Do have a more specific citation for the gemara in Berachot? ....where would I look if I wanted to see it inside?

Comment: There is no such a Gemara in Berachot - I just checked. it's not not in Tosafos there.

Comment: Danny Schoemann is 100% correct. It's not in Maseches Brachos. In my answer, I bring the Chessed Le’alafim, who quotes the Zohar.

Answer (score -1):

Answer to the second part:
[The Yeshiva World](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/224278/halachically-speaking-halachos-regarding-the-bathroom.html) says:

> Talking Many people have a habit of talking while in the bathroom
> (even when one is not actually “using the toilet”). However, this
> practice is forbidden. Many poskim maintain that talking in the
> bathroom is not allowed if it is not a great tzorech when one is not
> using the toilet.[10] Some people take the phone in the bathroom and
> talk to their friends without thinking anything is wrong with it, but
> this should not be done.[11] When one is giving their child a bath and
> they are there for an extended period of time then talking is
> permitted.[12] When one is using the toilet talking is
> forbidden.[13] If one is expecting an important phone call and one
> could lose a lot of money by not answering the phone then
> some poskim are lenient.[14] One should be careful not to talk to
> anyone in the bathroom since it might cause the one in the bathroom to
> talk back to you.[15]
>
> Sources:
>
> [10] Refer to Rashi Berochos 62a , “U’bais,” Rambam Hilchos
> De’os 5:6, Rama ibid, Be’er Heitiv 2, Levush 2, Mekor Chaim page
> 16, Machzik Beracha 3:6, Siddur Yaavetz page 87:1, Masef Lechul
> Hamachanus 3:8, Lekutei Maharich page 5b (old), Mishnah
> Berurah 3:4, Kaf Ha’chaim Y.D. 116:113, Ketzos
> Ha’shulchan 4:2, Minchas Yitzchok 4:61,Be’er Moshe 5:1, Doleh
> U’mashka page 9. The Torah L’shma 24 says it is permitted to talk in a
> bathroom for a tzorech and you may talk as much as you need.
>
> [11] Refer to Gemorah Sanhedrin 19a, Rashi “meshum,” Darchei
> Moshe 3:1, Magen Avraham 1, Be’er Heitiv 1, Shulchan Aruch Harav 3:2.
> Although the poskim say that women talk to each to each other in the
> bathroom to avoid an issur of yichud there with a man,  this does not
> apply today since we have separate bathrooms for men and woman (Bais
> Boruch 3:4, see Kaf Ha’chaim 3:5).
>
> [12] Horav Yisroel Belsky Shlita, see Yugel Yaakov pages 1-2.
>
> [13] Refer to Machzik Beracha 3:3: page 130, Siddur
> Yaavetz ibid, Chesed L’alafim 3:2, Mishnah Berurah 3:4, Kaf
> Ha’chaim 3:6, Toras Chaim page 8:2.
>
> [14] Otzros Yosef 1:6,  Sheiros Yosef  3:3, Yabea Omer 8:1, see Sharei
> Aaron 3:18.
>
> [15] V’ein Lumo Michshal 5:page 31:1.
>
> [16] Darchei Moshe 3:1, Rama 3:2, Levush

So you can't talk at all in the bathroom!

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question. Ok, so it's not good to talk in the bathroom, but when bathing that baby, can one tell the baby it is "lekovod shabbos"?

Comment: -1 for the same point as NBZ (This would be a great answer to the question: "May one talk in the bathroom?")

Comment: And just to clarify- if there was no situation at all that a person could talk in the bathroom, this could possibly be an answer to the question.