# Is it allowed to say Good Shabbos in the Mikva

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, mikvah-ritual-bath

One is not allowed to say Hashem's name in a bathroom.

[Shulchan Aruch OC 84](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.84.1?lang=bi&with=all) states one may not say Shalom in a mikva because it is one of Hashem's names.

According to the Zohar, "Shabbat" is also one of the names of Hashem, so does anyone say that one may not say Good Shabbos in a mikva?

Comment: Interesting question... according to the logic that this is a real concern, might one then also avoid saying שבת שלום altogether due to a concern of  מודים מודים?

Comment: See p. 35 here: https://beinenu.com/system/files/alonim/404_58_82.pdf

Comment: @Deuteronomy beinenu links need `?download=1` at the end https://beinenu.com/system/files/alonim/404_58_82.pdf?download=1. That seems to be a good answer to this question, no? As for the  מודים מודים, thanks for giving me something great to think about - could consider even asking as its own question?

Comment: First comment was just a related question that yours inspired :) Second was just a link to an analysis of a question that may raise sources (namely the Hesed le-Alafim) relevant to the analysis of yours. Thanks for reposting the fixed link (too late for me to edit the original comment).

Comment: "could consider even asking as its own question?" All yours if you wanna go for it... alley-oop

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88376/13811